# Beta testers are unable to install or update Windows Phone 8.0 app in beta

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have two apps in beta stage and now, probably after recent dashboard changes some of my beta testers are unable to install or update those beta apps. One of those apps was changed recently (using new dashboard), the second was unchanged for a month.

Error message on the phone: This app is not available for your device

- Testers are on the beta testers list, emails are separated with semicolon, all emails are from gmail with the same patters surname.firstname@gmail.com
- Both apps are WP 8.0 apps and testers have devices with WP 8.1
- Testers were able to install those apps about two weeks ago

Comment: You'll probably have more luck opening a support ticket to Microsoft

Comment: I did, but they asked me to follow the general steps of beta publish process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was a bug. Microsoft fixed that issue, and now mu beta testers are able to update apps without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and Microsoft said the same thing. My ticket is still open, but I found that if you switch the region in your phone to US (only region, not the language), the application becomes available for download.
It's not a perfect solution, but it can help you to test app.